# Get UDID from beta testers iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, udid

I am deploying a test version of my app over the air to my beta testers.  Before iOS 7, I could get their UDID by having them install an app like UDID Pro and having them email it to me.

How do I get the UDID from my beta testers if they have iOS 7, so I can set up the provisioning profiles for the Ad Hoc distribution of my app?

Comment: Is itunes an option? :)

Comment: xcode Organizer. maybe ask them to plug in the device after installing xcode and open the Organizer and then retrieve the UDID. :)

Comment: Please file a bug/feature request with Apple. You can reference bug #14666657 which I filed back in August. I suggested they either allow "Adhoc Helper" access to the real UDID or display the UDID in Settings/About.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting UDID programmatically will not work from iOS7.0 and upwards, since Apple apparently has moved it to "Private API" space for security reasons. However, you can still see the UDID of a device when it is connected to XCode (Xcode-> Organizer-> {Your Device Name}-> Identifier). You can also see it when the device is connected to iTunes, by clicking on the "Serial Number" once (it toggles between Serial No. and the UDID). You will have to ask your beta testers to find the device UDIDs this way and send you across, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use service http://udid.io

Send your users link "http://get.udid.io/?mail=your@mail.com" with your email filled. And users will need only 5 taps to send you UDID.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Provisioning Profile. TestFlightApp.com is a good third-party tool to use for this purpose. And it's free also.

Answer (score 0):

Your testers can find the UDID directly on their device without xCode and email it you can ask them to connect on http://www.easy-udid.com.

Answer (score 0):

Point your testers to this site and have them go through the instructions in there - http://whatsmyudid.com/ - it's easier than explaining it to them.