# How to get UDID of iOS Device Programmatically in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uuid, udid

i am using the below code to display the UDID of the device.
But its displaying the null value

i.e. 2014-05-12 11:56:06.896 LoginScreen[195:60b] deviceUDID: (null)

```
NSUUID *deviceId;
deviceId = [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor;
NSLog(@"deviceUDID: %@",deviceID);
```

Sorry to all of you. I made a silly mistake

Here NSUUID instance is deviceId and i am printing deviceID in NSLog :)

Now it is working for me. Thanks to everyone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now

Comment: A side note: this would be UUID and not UDID: [http://nshipster.com/uuid-udid-unique-identifier/].

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get UDID from beta testers iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672284/get-udid-from-beta-testers-ios-7)

Answer (score 5):

In order to get `UUID` of the device you can use the following line of code

```
[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

But you have to check whether the app is running on simulator or on device.

hope this helps you.

Comment: @Popeye that $ was put by mistake

Comment: OK no problems I will no remove my comment.

Answer (score 3):

Apple has hidden the UDID from all public APIs, starting with iOS 7. Any UDID that begins with FFFF is a fake ID.

Comment: so you mean to say that there is a no way to get UDID of the device in iOS 7 above

Comment: yes but you can use advertising identifier instead of UDID

Comment: OP is asking about `identifierForVendor` - which should be available. `advertisingIdentifier` can be opted out by user via settings.

Answer (score 0):

*Objective-C* :

```
NSString *strUUIDValue = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    NSLog(@"strUUIDValue : %@", strUUIDValue);
```

[image: Screenshot for Objective-C]

*Swift 2* :

```
let UUIDValue = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString
        print("UUID: \(UUIDValue)")
```

[image: Screenshot for Swift 2]

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *string = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]; 
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""]; 
string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"FFFFFFFF",string];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
NSUUID *deviceId;
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
deviceId = [NSUUID initWithUUIDString:@"UUID-STRING-VALUE"];
#else
deviceId = [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor;
#endif
```

OR

```
   NSString *uuid = nil;
   CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
   if (theUUID) {
    uuid = NSMakeCollectable(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, theUUID));
   [uuid autorelease];
   CFRelease(theUUID);
  }
```